# My python program that generates ten random multiplication questions. And tells user if the answer is right or wrong and prints the correct answer

Tags: python-3.x

```
My code so far looks like this

import random
Question1 = '3 * 5'
Question2 = '4 * 8'
Question3 = '3 * 4'
Question4 = '2 * 3'
Question5 = '5 * 5'
Question6 = '7 * 7'
Question7 = '8 * 5'
Question8 = '9 * 8'
Question9 = '2 * 7'
Question10 = '10 * 8'
Answer1 = 15
Answer2 = 32
Answer3 = 12
Answer4 = 6
Answer5 = 25
Answer6 = 49
Answer7 = 40
Answer8 = 72
Answer9 = 14
Answer10 = 80
questions = [Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4,Question5,Question6,Question7,Question8,Question9,Question10]
answers = [Answer1,Answer2,Answer3,Answer4,Answer5,Answer6,Answer7,Answer8,Answer9,Answer10]
random.shuffle(questions)
random.shuffle(answers)
if questions[0] == Question1:
print(Question1)
user_input = int(input('Enter the answer: '))
    if user_input == Answer1:
        print('right')
        else:
            print('wrong')
            print('The correct answer is:',Answer1)
```

I am getting a syntax error on 'else'. I checked the indentations and it's all correct. I am using IDLE Python 3.8, Somebody please guide me what I did wrong.

Comment: Indentation, `else` should be aligned with `if`. Also, make sure your questions are strings and not numbers. Finally, the way you have it now the answers probably won't match questions. Look into `eval` function to just evaluate the answer for a given question.

Comment: It's aligned with if. But I don't know why still its giving syntax error. I changed my questions as strings

Answer (score 0):

```
  import random

for i in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    answer = num1 * num2
    user_answer = int(input(f"What is {num1} x {num2}? "))
    if user_answer == answer:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong! The correct answer is {answer}.")
```